# Having trouble with this proof

Tags: propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I have to prove the following:
(((p ∨ q) ≡ (r ∨ s) ≡ (p ∨ q ∨ r ∨ s)) ∧ t ∧ u) → (r ∨ s). The proof is supposed to be relatively simple according to the professor but I have no clue where to start. Thanks.

Comment: What's about the table of truth?

Comment: Entering it into a truth table generator online, the whole thing is true but I have to use theorems to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be $p\lor q$, $B$ be $r\lor s$, and $C$ be $t\land u$,. In order to prove
$$(((A\leftrightarrow B)\leftrightarrow(A\lor B))\land C)\rightarrow B,$$
it is sufficient to prove
$$(P\leftrightarrow Q)\rightarrow B,$$
where $P$ is $A\leftrightarrow B$ and $Q$ is $A\lor B$.

Since $\neg Q\rightarrow P$, we have $(P\leftrightarrow Q)\rightarrow(P\land Q)$.

Moreover, $(P\land Q)\rightarrow B$, which ends the proof.